# Why does ng-hide and ng-show not work?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular

Good day. I used a few ways to use ng-show and ng-hide but neither of them work. First div should hide and seccond appear when click a button. Help me please! This is last way I tried:

```
<div class="parentDiv .col-lg-">
    <from class="centerMain">
        <div ng-show="showF" class="center-block">  <!-- this div should hides -->
            <div>
                <label  class="center-block">Введите PIN</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input name="userName" placeholder="1234" class="center-block inputLine">
            </div>          
            <div>
                <button ng-click="showF = !showF" class="center-block buttonBig">Установить PIN</button> <!-- this button makes hiding -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="!showF" class="center-block"> <!--this should appears -->
            <div>
                <label  class="center-block">Подтвердите пин</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input name="userName" placeholder="1234" class="center-block inputLine">
            </div>          
            <div>
                <button class="center-block buttonBig">Подтвердить</button> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </from>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is actually Angular2 then there is no `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, `ng-click` ...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , oh, that's how it is. thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 2 has deprecated many unnecessary Angular 1 directives.

You could use `[hidden]`/`[ngIf]` like `[hidden]="showF"` OR `*ngIf="showF"`

Also all the event based directive are deprecated and you can directly call a event on DOM by wrapping its name in `(eventName)`

```
(click)="myFunction()" //instead of ng-click
(focus)="myFunction()" //instead of ng-focus
```